# Re-using this code for multiple mapkit pin annotations

Tags: ios, mapkit, mkannotation

I have this code below working perfectly for a unique Pin and one annotation. I want to adapt it without too many changes to display more Pins, locations and annotations.

There is a class called `MyAnnotationPins` with the following lines:

MyAnnotationPins.h

```
@interface MyAnnotationPins : NSObject < MKAnnotation>
@property (nonatomic, readonly) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@property (nonatomic, readonly, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, readonly, copy) NSString *subtitle;
-(id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)annotCoordinate title:(NSString*)annotTitle subtitle:(NSString*)annotSubtitle;
```

MyAnnotationPins.m

```
@synthesize coordinate;
@synthesize subtitle;
@synthesize title;
-(id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)annotCoordinate title:(NSString*)annotTitle subtitle:(NSString*)annotSubtitle
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        coordinate = annotCoordinate;
        subtitle = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:annotSubtitle];
        title = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:annotTitle];
    }

    return self;
}
```

And at the view controller the following code:

SecondViewController.h

```
import "MyAnnotationPins.h"


@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController < MKMapViewDelegate > 

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;    
@property (strong, nonatomic) MyAnnotationPins* biblioAnnotation;
```

At the SecondViewController.m the implementation:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    mapView.delegate = self;

    MKCoordinateRegion mapRegion;
    mapRegion.center.latitude=-18.924129;
    mapRegion.center.longitude=-48.283963;
    mapRegion.span.latitudeDelta=0.2;
    mapRegion.span.longitudeDelta=0.2;

    [mapView setRegion:mapRegion animated:YES];

    ///// This is just for One annotaion/Pin on Map /////
    CLLocationCoordinate2D parliamentLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-18.924129, -48.283963);
    biblioAnnotation = [[MyAnnotationPins alloc]
                            initWithCoordinate:parliamentLocation
                            title:@"Ponto Biblioteca"
                            subtitle:@"Taxi proximo"];
    [mapView addAnnotation:biblioAnnotation];
```

If you want more than one pin and annotaion copy the CLLocation instance below and change the following atributes

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D secondLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(another latitude, another longitude);
secondAnnotation = [[MyAnnotationPins alloc]
                            initWithCoordinate:secondLocation
                            title:@"Second Title"
                            subtitle:@"Second subtitle"];
[mapView addAnnotation:secondAnnotation];  <code>
```

And so on for the third, fourth fifth etc. Do not forget to create the secondLocation proerty at your view controller like the first one in SecondViewController.h and also
    @synthesize secondAnnotation property at SecondViewController.m file

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) MyAnnotationPins* secondAnnotation;
```

Comment: Where will the data for the multiple locations come from?  Just create multiple `MyAnnotationPins` objects and call `addAnnotation` on them.  What's the exact problem?

Comment: The multiple locations will come from a list of latitudes and longitudes that I got from Google Maps. So I would create the others Pins manually in code, but Im not sure how to create multiple MyAnnotationPins objects in this code. I would start by creating a new MyAnnotationPin* newLocation in .h and the at .m file add and update the MKCoordinateRegion and CLLocationCoordinate2D codes. What and where to change them ? Latitude, Longitude, title, subtitles ?

Comment: Hey Anna. Just tested adding one more location/Pin/Annotation and woked. I will update the entire code by the end of the day so people will have a complete WORKING example of multiple Pin/Locations/Annotations code for iOS 5 and iPad. Actually I could not found any complete/working example here at stack. Just found it on a Wrox iPhone and iPad ebook for one location/pin/annotation. So now I will add the complete working updated example here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add them in a loop like so

```
for(X in Y)
{
 CLLocationCoordinate2D parliamentLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-18.924129, -48.283963);
MyAnnotationPins* biblioAnnotation = [[MyAnnotationPins alloc]
                        initWithCoordinate:parliamentLocation
                        title:@"Ponto Biblioteca"
                        subtitle:@"Taxi proximo"];
[mapView addAnnotation:biblioAnnotation];
}
```

As you loop through your list you can get the right coordinates and title for each one. This way you list can grow or shrink and you won't need to add third, fourth or fifth annotation properties.